# Insert a string/number into a specific cell of a csv file

Tags: perl, bash, csv, sed, awk

Basically right now I have a for loop running that runs a series of tests. Once the tests pass I input the results into a csv file:

```
for (( some statement ))
     do
         if[[ something ]]
              input this value into a specific row and column
         fi
     done
```

What I can't figure out right now is how to input a specific value into a specific cell in the csv file. I know in `awk` you can read a cell with this command:
`awk -v "row=2" -F'@' 'NR == row { print $2 }' some.csv` and this will print the cell in the 2nd row and 2nd column. I need something similar to this except it can input a value into a specific cell instead of read it. Is there a function that does this?

Comment: What about using that awk and outputting to another file?

Comment: I think that will take too long...I'm working with csv files that have around 1000 entries...recreating the file every time I think is a bit hectic...plus this file will be updating constantly

Comment: You can also consider using `sed -i` for this. If you paste some sample input we can provide some solutions. Is it just comma separated or with `@`?

Comment: it is separated with just a @. I've been playing around with awk...so far all I've come up with is this:
`awk -F, '{$(NF+1)=hi;}1' OFS=@ test.csv > output.csv` however this just replaces the last column with "hi", somehow i need to specify the row too

Comment: It might make sense to get all the values to be changed first, then do all the file updates in a single pass. Otherwise you'll be opening and reading the file many times, which may or may not make a difference for your use case.

Comment: well the thing is im using this data to graph as well. The purpose of this is to constantly monitor something and then input data as it update which in turn will also update the graph at the same time. If I were to first analyze everything then input the data all as one chunk...well then its not a real time graph. It's just for this purpose I need something that can function in a for-loop. Originally I did have what you proposed, inputting the data after as a chunk. Really appreciate the thought!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
awk -v value=$value -v row=$row -v col=$col 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="@"} NR==row {$col=value}1' file
```

And set the bash values `$value`, `$row` and `$col`. Then you can redirect and move to the original:

awk ... file > new_file && mv new_file file

This `&&` means that just if the first command (`awk...`) is executed successfully, then the second one will be performed.

#### Explanation

- `-v value=$value -v row=$row -v col=$col` pass the bash variables to `awk`. Note `value`, `row` and `col` could be other names, I just used the same as bash to make it easier to understand.
- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="@"}` set the Field Separator and Output Field Separator to be `@`. The `OFS="@"` is not necessary here, but can be useful in case you do some `print`.
- `NR==row {$col=value}` when the number of record (number of line here) is equal to `row`, then set the `col` column with `value` value.
- `1` perform the default `awk` action: `{print $0}`.

#### Example

```
$ cat a
hello@how@are@you
i@am@fine@thanks
hoho@haha@hehe

$ row=2
$ col=3
$ value="XXX"
$ awk -v value=$value -v row=$row -v col=$col 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="@"} NR==row {$col=value}1' a
hello@how@are@you
i@am@XXX@thanks
hoho@haha@hehe
```

Comment: you sir, are amazing! I've been looking into this problem for a long time. Thank you for your input!

Comment: If you don't mind me asking what is the purpose of BEGIN{FS=OFS=...} usually I've only seen one or the other used but not at the same time

Answer (score 2):

Your question has a 'perl' tag so here is a way to do it using [Tie::Array::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Array::CSV) which allows you to treat the CSV file as an array of arrays and use standard array operations:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::Array::CSV;

my $row = 2;
my $col = 3;
my $value = 'value';

my $filename = '/path/to/file.csv';
tie my @file, 'Tie::Array::CSV', $filename, sep_char => '@';
$file[$row][$col] = $value;
untie @file;
```

Answer (score 0):

using sed

```
row=2                                        # define the row number
col=3                                        # define the column number
value="value"                                # define the value you need change.
sed "$row s/[^@]\{1,\}/$value/$col" file.csv # use shell variable in sed to find row number first, then replace any word between @, and only replace the nominate column.
# So above sed command is converted to sed "2 s/[^@]\{1,\}/value/3" file.csv
```

If the above command is fine, and your sed command support the option `-i`, then run the command to change the content directly in file.csv

```
sed -i "$row s/[^@]\{1,\}/$value/$col" file.csv
```

Otherwise, you need export to temp file, and change the name back.

```
sed "$row s/[^@]\{1,\}/$value/$col" file.csv > temp.csv
mv temp.csv file.csv
```